# How to run tests set in Firefox and Chrome in the same time?

Tags: testing, browser, automation, cypress

The target is to run tests in 2 browsers, the test script should be modified. What was done:   if (Cypress.isBrowser('chrome') & Cypress.isBrowser('firefox')), as results test is running, but in default browser, what is electron or it depends what is selected browser in cypress runner. I have 3 browsers now.  I did ./node_modules/.bin/cypress run --browser chrome this works, but unfortunately looks like it's impossible to ./node_modules/.bin/cypress run --browser chrome and ./node_modules/.bin/cypress run --browser Firefox.  Also I added script in package .json file - "cypress-multi-browsers": "npm run unified-cypress-dev -- --browser firefox & npm run unified-cypress-dev -- --browser chrome", but getting errors about Firefox security.

Any suggestions?

Many thanks )

Comment: Two different terminals, two different pipelines. One for each browser. This doesn't work?

Comment: I'm running test from Visual Studio terminal.

Comment: another guess is need to figure out how to run headless chrome and firefox in codefresh.